# How to check multiple matching words with regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey I have code like this

```
var text = "We are downing to earth"
var regexes = "earth|art|ear"
if (regexes.length) {
    var reg = new RegExp(regexes, "ig");
    console.log(reg)
    while ((regsult = reg.exec(text)) !== null) {
      var word = regsult[0];
      console.log(word)
    }
  }
```

I want to get matching words from text. It should have "earth", "art" and "ear" as well. Because "earth" consist of those substring. Instead, it only produce "earth".

Is there any mistake with my regex pattern?
Or should I use another approach in JS?

Thanks

Comment: yes, it should be like that

Comment: I think your original problem is to find matching words in JavaScript. If so you can may break your `RegExp` into `n` different RegExp (where `n` is the number of words) and then run each RegExp on the sentence to know the words which are present in the text. Also if you are looking for exact match for words you can use simple string match with `indexOf` rather than RegExp. Eg fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtxk3zdn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in another answer, a single regexp cannot match multiple overlapping alternatives. In your case, simply do a separate regexp test for each word you are looking for:

```
var text = "We are downing to earth"
var regexes = ["earth", "art", "ear"];

var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < regexes.length; i++ ) {
  var word = regexes[i];
  if (text.match(word) results.push(word);
}
```

You could tighten this up a little bit by doing

```
regexes . filter(function(word) { return (text.match(word) || [])[0]; });
```

If your "regexes" are actually just strings, you could just use `indexOf` and keep things simpler:

```
regexes . filter(function(word) { return text.indexOf(word) !== -1; });
```

Comment: This is of course much more sensible than trying to construct a wildly nested regex.

Comment: okay, I use `str.indexOf` to accomplish this. Thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You only get `earth` as a match because the regex engine has matched `earth` as the first alternative and then moved on in the source string, oblivious to the fact that you could also have matched `ear` or `art`. This is expected behavior with all regex engines - they don't try to return all possible matches, just the first one, and matches generally can't overlap.

Whether `earth` or  `ear` is returned depends on the regex engine. A POSIX ERE engine will always return the leftmost, longest match, whereas most current regex engines (including JavaScript's) will return the first possible match, depending on the order of alternation in the regex.

So `art|earth|ear` would return `earth`, whereas `ear|art|earth` would return `ear`.

You *can* make the regex find overlapping matches (as long as they start in different positions in the string) by using [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?=(ear|earth|art))
```

will find `ear` and `art`, but not `earth` because it starts at the same position as `ear`. Note that you must not look for the regex' entire match (`regsult[0]` in your code) in this case but for the content of the [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), in this case (`regsult[1]`).

The only way around this that I can think of at the moment would be to use

```
(?=(ear(th)?|art))
```

which would have a result like `[["", "ear", "th"], ["", "art", undefined]]`.

Comment: wooh, thanks and a concise explanation. But i should go with "str.indexOf" instead :)